# SQL 2005 compare Date saved as VARCHAR

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, date, varchar

I have saved dates as VARCHAR in sql server 2005
now I want to select all dates before 2013 and I can't.

WDATE 09/01/2012
      08/13/2012

I want to compare those dates with any other date
I am using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM Work_Order
WHERE  WDATE  < '09/02/2012'
```

but it subtract days then months then years which is not my case

Comment: What date format have you used?

Comment: Where cast varchar to date column  <= 1/1/2011

Comment: You need to post the code or conversion expression that you have tried in order for people to help you.

Comment: I think sql 20005 does not provide date data type

Comment: No, but it does have a `datetime` type:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819(v=sql.90).aspx.  You will be much better off using a true date column rather than a character string.

Comment: @AhmedKato Can you please post some examples of your data stored as varchar ? To see how to convert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing your updated question, you cannot do what you want (selecting records before some date) if your column is defined as `VARCHAR`.  You need to store it as a `DATETIME` value or CAST it, perhaps like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   Work_Order 
WHERE  CAST(WDATE as DATETIME)  < CAST('09/02/2012' as DATETIME)
```

I don't have SQL SERVER 2005 myself, so the syntax is just a guess.

Comment: The syntax should be fine, the problem with this approach is that it is culture-sensitive, e.g. in the US it will be using MM/DD/YYYY and in the UK DD/MM/YYYY or so...

Comment: Yes; the right-hand side really should be a constant (and not use CAST), but I don't know the proper SQL Server 2005 syntax.  Feel free to edit the answer!

Comment: thanks it works for me on 2008 r2 , will try it with 2005

Comment: Thanks for the "permission" to edit Bob, but I won't - I don't think that Ahmed cares, and since the question is already scored -4 it's not going to be seen as an important QA resource anyways.